Trouble while trying to erase an nfcA tag
I’m trying to erase data from an NFC tag using the following code. The goal is to overwrite all user-memory pages (from page 4 to 39) with zeros. However, the data remains unchanged on the tag even after running the code.
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/platform_tags.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class NfcService {
  final NfcManager _nfcManager = NfcManager.instance;
  bool _isScanning = false;

  Future<void> eraseTag() async {
    if (_isScanning) return;

    _isScanning = true;

    try {
      await _nfcManager.startSession(
        onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
          try {
            final nfca = NfcA.from(tag);
            if (nfca != null) {
              try {
                for (int page = 4; page < 40; page++) {
                  await nfca.transceive(
                    data: Uint8List.fromList([0xA0, page, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]),
                  );
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print('Error erasing tag: ${e.toString()}');
              }
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error accessing NFC tag: ${e.toString()}');
          } finally {
            _isScanning = false;
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error starting NFC session: ${e.toString()}');
      _isScanning = false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> startScanning(
    Function(String) onDataRead,
    Function(String) onError,
  ) async {
    if (_isScanning) return;

    _isScanning = true;

    try {
      await _nfcManager.startSession(
        onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
          try {
            final nfca = NfcA.from(tag);
            if (nfca != null) {
              try {
                const int startPage = 4; // Starting from page 4
                const int maxPages = 12; // Adjust as needed
                StringBuffer allData = StringBuffer();

                for (int page = startPage; page < maxPages; page++) {
                  try {
                    final response = await nfca.transceive(
                      data: Uint8List.fromList([0x30, page]), // READ command
                    );

                    // Log raw data in hexadecimal format
                    String hexData = response
                        .map((byte) => byte.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0'))
                        .join(' ');
                    print('Page $page raw data (hex): $hexData');

                    // Append the page data to the buffer
                    allData.writeln(hexData);
                  } catch (e) {
                    print('Error reading page $page: ${e.toString()}');
                  }
                }

                // Pass the concatenated data to onDataRead
                onDataRead(allData.toString());
              } catch (e) {
                onError('Error in transceive operation: ${e.toString()}');
              }
            } else {
              onError('NFC A tag not found.');
            }
          } catch (e) {
            onError('Error reading NFC tag: ${e.toString()}');
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      onError('Error starting NFC session: ${e.toString()}');
    } finally {
      _isScanning = false;
    }
  }

  void stopScanning() {
    if (_isScanning) {
      _nfcManager.stopSession();
      _isScanning = false;
    }
  }
}


I’ve tried using various loops to ensure that all pages are addressed.
I’ve checked the command for writing zeros and it seems to be in the correct format.
The eraseTag method is intended to overwrite pages 4 to 39 with zeros, but the data remains unchanged.

Have you tried with 0xA0 ?

@MansoorMalik oh my God we completely forgot about it, i'll try and let you know
thank youu

@MansoorMalik didn't work
i updated the code if you wanna check

NfcA can cover a lot of different types of Tags with many different memory access methods but as you are trying to write to pages then the Tag is likely to be something like an NTAG 2xx series or Mifare Classic
NTAG 2xx series Tags have 4 byte memory pages.
Mifare Classic Tags have 16 byte memory pages.
your write command
data: Uint8List.fromList([0xA0, page, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]),
only provides 3 bytes so a Tag should respond with a "Not OK" response.
try writing 4 bytes
e.g.
data: Uint8List.fromList([0xA2, page, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]),
Note that 0xA0 needs 16-byte Data, only least significant
4 bytes are written (on a NTAG series)
But if the Tag is a Mifare Classic then use 0xA0 and provide 16 bytes of zero data.

it's an iso 14443-3A tag

iso 14443-3A is the same as saying NfcA, there are still many different tags with different structures and commands that could confirm to that standard, I've outline the commands for 2 of the most common types.
